# Set the number of iterations gpt-2

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I'm fine tunning a gpt-2 model following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@ngwaifoong92/beginners-guide-to-retrain-gpt-2-117m-to-generate-custom-text-content-8bb5363d8b7f

With is associated GitHub repository:

https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2

I have been able to replicate the examples, my issue is that I'm not fiding a parameter to set the number of iterations. Basically the training script shows a sample every 100 iterations and save a model version every 1000 iterations. But I'm not finding a parameter to train it for say, 5000 iterations and then close it.

The script for training is here: https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2/blob/finetuning/train.py

I suspect it should be inside this loop, but really don't get to understand the code:

```
    try:
        while True:
            if counter % args.save_every == 0:
                save()
            if counter % args.sample_every == 0:
                generate_samples()
            if args.val_every > 0 and (counter % args.val_every == 0 or counter == 1):
                validation()

            if args.accumulate_gradients > 1:
                sess.run(opt_reset)
                for _ in range(args.accumulate_gradients):
                    sess.run(
                        opt_compute, feed_dict={context: sample_batch()})
                (v_loss, v_summary) = sess.run((opt_apply, summaries))
            else:
                (_, v_loss, v_summary) = sess.run(
                    (opt_apply, loss, summaries),
                    feed_dict={context: sample_batch()})

            summary_log.add_summary(v_summary, counter)

            avg_loss = (avg_loss[0] * 0.99 + v_loss,
                        avg_loss[1] * 0.99 + 1.0)

            print(
                '[{counter} | {time:2.2f}] loss={loss:2.2f} avg={avg:2.2f}'
                .format(
                    counter=counter,
                    time=time.time() - start_time,
                    loss=v_loss,
                    avg=avg_loss[0] / avg_loss[1]))

            counter += 1
```

Comment: please add the script as part of the post, and not as a link

Comment: @Mark.F Code is 300 lines

Comment: It seems like you need to interrupt the script to stop training (weird if true). See the exception catch `except KeyboardInterrupt: print('interrupted') save()`